# VueJS Grpc-Web module not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, grpc, grpc-web

I've created a fresh VueJS application with TypeScript functionality.

When I generate using:

```
protoc -I=. service.proto --js_out=import_style=typescript:. --grpc web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcwebtext:.
```

I get the following files:

[image]

When I move them to `src/_protos` in my VueJS project and try to `import { PlatformClient } from '@/_protos/ServiceServiceClientPb';` it gives me the following error:

```
Failed to compile.
./src/_protos/ServiceServiceClientPb.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './service_pb' in '/Users/theobouwman/dev/woodyshousing/woody_web/src/_protos'
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is resolved in https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/431.

In short, `--js_out=import_style=typescript:.` is not supposed to work. You need to do `--js_out=import_style=commonjs:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs+dts,mode=grpcwebtext:.`

Comment: I indeed found that solution.